# why parameters in socket_select method sent by reference?

Tags: sockets, serversocket

Hi every body I need your help.

could any one explain for me why parameters in the socket_select ( **array &$read , array &$write , array &$except** , int $tv_sec [, int $tv_usec = 0 ] ) are sent by reference and how the method effect on those parameters.

thanks every body.

Comment: [Read the manual.](http://php.net/socket_select) If you've already done that, tell us what parts you don't understand.

Comment: @duskwuff I have read, but I do not understand what will happen for read ,write and except arrays and how the method effect on them.

I am confused a little because I have read also the code written in last section of this article http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/ which speak about  Handling Connections and I did not understand it.

Comment: In general, parameters are passed by reference so that the called function can modify the values upon return. The manual explains that the modified parameters will be the set of sockets that have the corresponding property. If you need more information, then your question is either too vague or too broad. Please improve your question.